# Extjs4 RESTful CRUD grid with Spring Controllers

Tags: spring, rest, datagrid, extjs4

I am new to Extjs4 and the javascript world in general. I have looked up the documentation and samples and trying to get a basic CRUD grid up and running with my spring backend.

I have a confusion related to the proxy in extjs, are they in the store or model according to the MVC paradigm ?

I have a controller.js defined which wraps these up together.
I would have thought that the REST calls would be made accroding to the urls being specified, which it is for now , but a create call is still sending the entire list. I am using jackson at the backend for automatic conversion to java objects but somehow that is not working (for add and update only).

How do i link these all up ?

a) Add a user .. do i create a new UserModel and then invoke a rest call like so or is it automatically supported by the proxy specified in the model ?

```
var record = new App.model.UserModel();
     store = Ext.getStore('UsersStore');
     store.insert(0, record);
     store.save();  // .. this invokes the /createUser method 
                    //   .. what about /update ?
```

b) I am using the RowEditing plugin .. how can i fetch the roweditor in my controller.js where the reference for the view is available

Thanks in advance

relevant code listings ...

//UserController.js

```
Ext.define('App.controller.UsersController', {
extend : 'Ext.app.Controller',
init: function() {
    this.control({
        'userList button[action=add]' : {
                click : this.editUser
            }         });    },
views : ['user.List','user.Edit'],
stores : ['UsersStore'] ,
models : ['UserModel'],
editUser : function(grid,record)
{
    // empty record
     var record = new App.model.UserModel();
     // created new record

//How to get a reference to the roweditor here and then save that to the backend ?

 //store = Ext.getStore('UsersStore');
     //store.insert(0, record);
     //store.save();
    // this.getView('user.List').getP('rowEditor').startEdit(0, 0);

}});
```

//List.js

```
var rowEditor = Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.RowEditing', {
clicksToEdit: 2
 }
Ext.define('App.view.user.List' ,{
extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
alias : 'widget.userList',
title : 'All Users',
store : 'UsersStore',
selType: 'rowmodel',
plugins: rowEditor,
initComponent: function() {
    this.columns = [
        {header: 'SNo',  dataIndex: 'userID', width:50},
        {header: 'UID',  dataIndex: 'userUID',  flex: 1, editor: 'textfield', allowBlank:false},
        {header: 'Name',  dataIndex: 'userName',  flex: 1, editor:'textfield',allowBlank:false},
        {   header: 'Level',  dataIndex: 'userLevel',  flex: 1,
            editor: {xtype: 'combobox', typeAhead: true, triggerAction: 'all', selectionOnTab:true,
                     store : [
                              ['Level 1','Level 1'],
                              ['Level 2','Level 2'],
                              ['Level 3','Level 3']

                            ]
                }
        },
        {header: 'Email', dataIndex: 'emailID', flex: 1, editor: 'textfield'}
    ];
    this.callParent(arguments);
},
dockedItems : [{
    xtype : 'toolbar',
    items : [{
         text: 'Add',
         iconCls: 'icon-add',
         action: 'add'

    }]
}]});
```

//Model.js

```
Ext.define('App.model.UserModel', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
fields: ['userID','userUID','userName', 'userLevel' ,'emailID'],
proxy : {
    type: 'ajax',
    api :
        {
            read : 'rest/user/fetchAll',
            update:'rest/user/updateUser',
            create :'rest/user/createUser',
            destroy : 'rest/user/deleteUser'
        },

    reader :
        {
        type : 'json',
        root : 'users',
        successProperty : 'success'
        },

    writer :
        {
        type : 'json',
        allowSingle : 'true'
        }
}});
```

//UserStore

```
Ext.define('App.store.UsersStore', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
model: 'App.model.UserModel',
autoLoad : true});
```

//Sample Java controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/rest/user")
public class UserController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/fetchAll" ,  method= RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody Map<String,? extends Object> 
    fetchUsers()            {
    Map<String,Object> responseMap = new HashMap<String,Object>();
    responseMap.put("success",true);
    responseMap.put("users",userService.getUserRepository().findAll());
    return responseMap;  }

    // was expecting a single object here ?

@RequestMapping(value = "/createUser")
public @ResponseBody Map<String,? extends Object> 
                         createUser(@RequestBody    List<User> users) 
 {  ...   }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. I would put Proxy's inside store objects, not models. But that just personal preference.
2. When you add record to the store object, if it has autoSync property set to true it would automatically generate create request. What exactly is happening with your create request? What is being sent?

Comment: Two diff things : 1) i want to add a record via the rowediting plugin. So how do i reference that in the view ? Once i do that on the 'update' property for that row do i need to fire the create  request..because it is does not do it automatically ... ?     2) If i manually test the creation of a record : create new model, insert into store and save store  then a create request is sent to the server with the entire data set present in the grid , and i want only the new record to be sent ideally ..shud not that be the behaviour ?

Comment: 1. Presumable you have button or menu item to create new record, right? Then just do rowEditor.startEdit(0,0) in your controller.

Comment: 2. Yes, only new record should have being sent

Comment: 1. Thanks, ok as i mentioned i am new to js so i guess the variable is available for access. But if i had not created a variable for the plugin and i had that code instead inside the plugin section of the view, how would i be able to access 'rowEditor' plugin from the view. I was looking at the documentation and getPlugin('pluginId') would have worked (after i create the pluginId for the rowEditor) but it did not, no such method getPlugin available on the view ?

Comment: 2. for this, am i doing something wrong ? store.save() sents the entire list ... if i remove the allowSingle : true property on the json write it is the same behaviour

Comment: You can create property in your view and store rowEditor there

Comment: You don't need to do store.save() - do store.sync() if you don't have autoSync property. See if it helps

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9869/discussion-between-sunny-and-sha)

Answer (score 0):

After trying out Sha's comments above, i was finally able to nail the issue.
The problem is with the json reader

```
reader :
    {
    type : 'json',
    root : 'users',
    successProperty : 'success'
    //added
    idProperty : 'userID'
    },
```

I had to add the idProperty to make Json recognize the dirty record, else it treats everything as a new record and sends back the whole list

Comment: I would suggest moving idProperty to the model definition. Glad that I was able to help